# How to comparing two array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hi i have two arrays comparing both depending upon common fq_id

```
var array1 =[
  {"description":" Virat Kohli","fq_id":156},{"description":" Lokesh Rahul","fq_id":156},{"description":"Chateshwar Pujara","fq_id":156},{"description":"Ajinke Rahane","fq_id":156}]

var array2 = [
  {"ans_description":"who is better?","fq_id":156}]
```

after matching fq_id

resulting array should be as follows

```
result = [{
description:who is better?,
options:["Virat Kohli","Lokesh Rahul","Chateshwar Pujara","Rahane"]
}]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Highlight that command + k to indent your code

Comment: What's the question? _"resulting array should be as follows"_ are you asking us to do your work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not shows any sign of effort.

Comment: guys i am new to javascript pls co-operate

Comment: Have a look at the array methods, you can solve this pretty easily with one of them or some simple for-loops.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you're having trouble with. Regarding your sample input data, *all* of the IDs match - is that on purpose?

Comment: Please revise your question and elaborate on the problem. It sounds like you want to complete a custom routine across the arrays. The fundamental idea to touch all of the items in the arrays is to loop across one array and then loop across the other array on every item of the first loop. There are many performance improvements that can be made to this process but work towards a working example first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the new object with the filtered items.

Simple version

```js
var array1 = [{ description: "Virat Kohli", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Lokesh Rahul", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Chateshwar Pujara", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Ajinke Rahane", fq_id: 156 }],
    array2 = [{ ans_description: "who is better?", fq_id: 156 }],
    result = array2.map(a => ({
        description: a.ans_description,
        options: array1.filter(b => a.fq_id === b.fq_id).map(a => a.description)
    }));

console.log(result);
```

Version with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var array1 = [{ description: "Virat Kohli", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Lokesh Rahul", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Chateshwar Pujara", fq_id: 156 }, { description: "Ajinke Rahane", fq_id: 156 }],
    array2 = [{ ans_description: "who is better?", fq_id: 156 }],
    map = new Map,
    result = array2.map(a => map.set(a.fq_id, {
        description: a.ans_description,
        options: []
    }).get(a.fq_id));

array1.forEach(a => map.has(a.fq_id) && map.get(a.fq_id).options.push(a.description));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array1 =[
  {"description":" Virat Kohli","fq_id":156},{"description":" Lokesh Rahul","fq_id":146},{"description":"Chateshwar Pujara","fq_id":157},{"description":"Ajinke Rahane","fq_id":156}]

var array2 = [
  {"ans_description":"who is better?","fq_id":156}]

var result = [{'description':array2[0].ans_description, 'options':[]}]

for(var i = 0; i<array1.length; i++) {
 if(array1[i].fq_id === array2[0].fq_id){ 
   result[0].options.push([array1[i].description])
 }
}
```